# Visual Studio 2015 vdproj file into Visual Studio 2022

Tags: installation, windows-installer, vdproj

I'm migrating a Visual Studio 2015 solution to Visual Studio 2022.  The solution includes a "Setup and Deployment" vdproj project and Studio 2022 says it is incompatible.  Is there an Add-in that I need?  How can I bring in the existing (2015) installation project?

Answer (score 2):

You can download an official Microsoft extension that provides support for Visual Studio Installer Projects in Visual Studio 2022.

[Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects)

Comment: Needs more explanation and details to support the qustion, Maybe better be a comment

Comment: The documentation is available here: https://aka.ms/vdproj-docs, as written on the page I linked.